# Como introduzco un Archivo txt dentro de un JtextArea java

Tags: java, textarea

Tengo entendido que es con un ciclo pero he estado intentado esto y no sale, sale la ventana y el área de texto con el botón pero no sale lo que se encuentra en mi archivo txt
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Consultar extends JFrame{
    //private Enlace enlace;
    private JButton consultar;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane1;

```
public Consultar(){
    super("Consulta");
    setLayout(null);
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    scrollpane1=new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollpane1.setBounds(40,40,300,200);
    add(scrollpane1);

    consultar = new JButton("Cosultar");
    consultar.setBounds(40,260,100,30);
    add(consultar);
}           

public static void main(String args[]) {
    File archivo;
    try{
        archivo = new File("/Users/mahlul/Desktop/Programa/ArchivoNuevo.txt");
        if (archivo.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("");
        } 
    }catch(Throwable e){

    }
    Consultar consultarl = new Consultar();
    consultarl.setBounds(0,0,400,380);
    consultarl.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe de ser algo como esto

```
String codigo = new String(), path = "la ruta de tu archivo";
            File archivo = new File(path);

            FileReader fr = null;
            BufferedReader entrada = null;
            try {
                fr = new FileReader(path);
                entrada = new BufferedReader(fr);

                while(entrada.ready()){
                    codigo += entrada.readLine();
                }

            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try{                    
                    if(null != fr){   
                        fr.close();     
                    }                  
                }catch (Exception e2){ 
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
miTextArea.setText(codigo);
```

Por que en tu ejemplo, solo veo que lo lees y en caso de que no exista, lo creas, prueba lo que te mandé

Comment: @arcangel-abbatu mira, ese `miTextArea.setText(codigo)` es para mi caso, en el tuyo tu text area no se llama **miTextArea** en tu código  se llama **textArea** nada mas

Answer (score 0):

Hola gracias Por ayudarme me salen 2 errores
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

public class Consultar extends JFrame{
    //private Enlace enlace;
    private JButton consultar;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane1;

```
public Consultar(){
    super("Consulta");
    setLayout(null);
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    scrollpane1=new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollpane1.setBounds(40,40,300,200);
    add(scrollpane1);

    consultar = new JButton("Cosultar");
    consultar.setBounds(40,260,100,30);
    add(consultar);
}

    public static void main(String args[]){   
    Consultar consultarl = new Consultar();
    consultarl.setBounds(0,0,400,380);
    consultarl.setVisible(true);

    String codigo = new String(), path = "C:/UsersLuzmaDesktop/SegundoParcial/ArchivoNuevo.txt";
    File archivo = new File(path);

    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader entrada = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(path);
           entrada = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while(entrada.ready()){
                codigo += entrada.readLine();
            }
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{                    
                if(null != fr){   
                    fr.close();     
                }                  
            }catch (Exception e2){ 
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
miTextArea.setText(codigo);
```

}